# Can I get the ErrorMessage value from DataAnnotation markup?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working on having a single source for my validation messages. I would like it to be the DataAnnotations. Is there a way I can get the ErrorMessage and use it in code? I am guessing I'd have to use Reflection, but I might be wrong. I also don't know what to do with Reflection.

```cs
public class PersonDataModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "FullName is required.")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this with reflection using `GetCustomAttributes`:

```cs
string mesage = typeof(PersonDataModel)

    // Get the property owning the attribute instance:
    .GetProperty(nameof(PersonDataModel.FullName))

    // Get all attributes for the property:
    .GetCustomAttributes(true)

    // Filter the attributes by the desired DataAnnotation attribute
    .OfType<RequiredAttribute>()

    // If there is at least one instance of the desired annotation, get that
    .FirstOrDefault()

    // Assuming we found the attribute, get the ErrorMessage property.
    ?.ErrorMessage;
```

---

If you do this often, you might create a helper method. Here's an example extension method for `Type`:

```cs
public static class ModelExtensions {
    /// <summary>
    /// Get an attribute of type <typeparamref name="T"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The attribute type to get.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="type">
    /// The type with a property that owns an instance of <typeparamref name="T"/>.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="propertyName">
    /// The property that owns an instance of <typeparamref name="T"/>.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>The attribute, if found.</returns>
    public static T GetAttributeOrDefault<T>(this Type type, string propertyName) => type
        .GetProperty(propertyName)
        .GetCustomAttributes(true)
        .OfType<T>()
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Use it like:

```cs
string message = typeof(PersonDataModel)
    .GetAttributeOrDefault<RequiredAttribute>(nameof(PersonDataModel.FullName))
    ?.ErrorMessage;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display it in UI - you can use  `Html.ValidationMessageFor()` to show a message for a specific property of the model.

For fetching the errors in controller->

```
    var errors = ModelState.Select(state => state.Value.Errors)
                           .Where(errors=>errors.Count>0)
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: Note, this only works (out-of-the-box) with Razor (Pages, MVC5, etc.)